# Implementing Bitrix24 crm.deal.add in ASP.NET Core Web API 6.0 with Authentication

Tags: asp.net, task, addition, crm, bitrix

I'm working on integrating Bitrix24's crm.deal.add method into an ASP.NET Core Web API 6.0 application. The objective is to create new deals in Bitrix24, passing data like first name, last name, email, and product name. I have been provided with a username and password for authentication.

Could anyone share an example or guide on how to implement the crm.deal.add method in ASP.NET Core, particularly with regard to handling authentication with Bitrix24? I haven't been able to find relevant .NET Core examples or documentation online.

Any pointers, code snippets, or references to similar implementations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!